# Installing LyX over a vanilla TeXLive

Tags: lyx, texlive, installing, linux

As the title says, I would like to install LyX over a vanilla TeXLive. However, when I do

```
yum install lyx
```

the whole distro TeXLive is set to be installed, which I obviously don't want. On the other hand, I didn't find RPMs for LyX on its website. So how can I install LyX in this situation? I'm running TL2014 on Fedora 20.

Comment: Try installing a dummy package: https://copr-fe.cloud.fedoraproject.org/coprs/fatka/texlive-dummy/

Comment: You can try also to compile the source code instead istall a .rpm package.

Comment: @DG' Unfortunately the `texlive-dummy` isn't set properly, so it doesn't work :-/

Comment: @yo' A dummy package is the way to go, IMNSHO. I apparently had to modify the code I found in order to get it to work properly, so I've pasted what I actually ended up using below. The licence statement is the original and also applies to whatever modifications I made to get it working. Once you do this, you never have to think about this again. Installing editors etc. with `yum` Just Works and it never tries to install an additional copy of TeX Live. (At least, it has worked great for me so far.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rpm of 2.1.2 version for x64 can be downloaded [here](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/27461276/dir/fedora_20/com/lyx-2.1.2-1.fc20.x86_64.rpm.html). In the same page you can check the dependencies, in case there are some extra packages you may have to install.

Once you have the rpm file, follow the instructions provided in the askfedora forum [here](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/51707/use-own-texlive-installation/). In terminal:

```
rpm -Uvh --nodeps lyx-2.1.2-1.fc20.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: It works, thanks. You can even convince `yum` to download the file for you using `yum --downloadonly`, but it's a bit complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that I cannot remember where exactly I got the original code for this, but it seems that I modified it at some point as I have versioning notes.

## The Package Specification

Anyway, here is the `.spec` file I used to create an `.rpm` for a dummy package:

```
Name:    texlive2012-dummy-cfr
Version: 1.0
Release: 2%{?dist}
Summary: This is a fake TeXLive package
Group:   Applications/Publishing
License: GPLv2 and BSD and Public Domain and LGPLv2+ and GPLv2+ and LPPL
BuildRoot: %(mktemp -ud %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-XXXXXX)                   
Provides: config(texlive)
Provides: kpathsea libkpathsea.so.4()
Provides: tetex tetex-dvips tetex-fonts tetex-latex tex 
Provides: tex(dvips) tex(latex) tex(tex) tex-preview texinfo-tex
Provides: texlive texlive-afm texlive-context texlive-doc texlive-doc-errata
Provides: texlive-dvips texlive-dviutils texlive-east-asian texlive-fonts
Provides: texlive-texmf texlive-latex texlive-utils texlive-xetex          
Provides: texlive-texmf-afm texlive-texmf-context texlive-texmf-doc texlive-texmf-dvips                               
Provides: texlive-texmf-errata texlive-texmf-errata-afm texlive-texmf-errata-context
Provides: texlive-texmf-errata-doc texlive-texmf-errata-dvips texlive-texmf-errata-east-asian
Provides: texlive-texmf-errata-fonts texlive-texmf-errata-latex texlive-texmf-errata-xetex                      
Provides: texlive-texmf-fonts texlive-texmf-latex texlive-texmf-xetex                             
Provides: tetex-IEEEtran tetex-dvipost tetex-elsevier tetex-tex4ht
Provides: tetex-xdvi xdvik

%description
This was necessary to have a tlmgr-based installation of texlive and all the rpm packages that requires texlive (e.g., a2ps and R-core) still installable.

%prep

%build

%install
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
%doc

%changelog
```

## How It Works

When compiled into `.rpm` form, you get something like `texlive2012-dummy-cfr-1.0-2.fc17.x86_64.rpm`. (Obviously, you'll get a different version and you can edit it to avoid the `cfr` or whatever.) You just install that and it takes care of everything. At least, it has for me. (I am now using version 21 of Fedora and haven't even had to recreate it to keep the system happy. `fedup` will complain no update is available if you upgrade your system, but that's expected and does no harm.)

## Advantages

The enormous advantage of this method is that you can then install whatever TeX-dependent software you like just using `yum install ...` (or whatever GUI interface you prefer, obviously).

## How To Build The Package

To build the `.rpm`, make a clean directory and create `texlive2012-dummy-cfr.spec` with the code above as content. (Or edit the file name and `Name` field in the spec.)

Then run

```
rpmbuild -bb texlive2012-dummy-cfr.spec
```

Read the output which will tell you where the .rpm is. For example, I get:

```
Wrote: /home/software/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/texlive2012-dummy-cfr-1.0-2.fc21.x86_64.rpm
```

So I know that the `.rpm` I want to install is at `/home/software/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/texlive2012-dummy-cfr-1.0-2.fc21.x86_64.rpm`.

[It has changed name because I just rebuilt it and I'm now using Fedora 21 rather than 17.]

Comment: Any idea if for fedora 23 is the same??

Comment: @murpholinox I'm still using this on Fedora 23. (I'm not even sure I rebuilt it - I don't remember. But nothing else.) Probably you should use `dnf` to install it rather than`yum` but that's just because they've changed to `dnf` generally so `yum` is generally deprecated. The TeX Live specific stuff is just the same.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution right now is to install the texlive-dummy package from ctan from here:

https://ctan.org/tex-archive/support/texlive/texlive-dummy/EnterpriseLinux-7

It works on RHEL, CentOS, AlmaLinux, etc. and it should also work on Fedora.